# Asciidoc : Problem with the size of the HTML to render from an .adoc file

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest-assured, asciidoc, spring-restdocs

I'm working on enhancing the API documentation of a Spring Boot project using rest-docs, rest assured and asciidoctor.

I'm writing integration tests to generate the snippets for each API endpoint, write the `.adoc` file that references all the snippets , process the `.adoc` file with `asciidoctor-maven-plugin` and transform it to a HTML file during the build, then copy the HTML file inside the `jar` to be served as a static content when the application is running.
Everything started to work fine in the beginning, until the size of the HTML started increasing.
when I started documenting more APIs, the html page that used to be accessible from this URL http://localhost:8080/docs/api-docs.html is now a blank page.

but when I access the page by opening the file in `/target/generated-docs/api-docs.html`, it works fine on the browser, which means there's a problem with the jar serving the HTML file.

[image: Generated files structure]

The console output when trying to access this url http://localhost:8080/docs/api-docs.html

```
2020-02-03 11:45:36.645 DEBUG 22302 --- [tp1360215046-21] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: java.lang.IllegalStateException: s=OPEN,api=BLOCKED,sc=false,e=null
2020-02-03 11:45:36.651  WARN 22302 --- [tp1360215046-21] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel     : /docs/api-docs.html

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: s=OPEN,api=BLOCKED,sc=false,e=null
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:503) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.3.jar!/:4.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.3.jar!/:4.0.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:755) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1617) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:226) ~[websocket-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at com.tes.config.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:55) ~[classes!/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:590) ~[jetty-security-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1607) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1297) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1577) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1212) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:767) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311) ~[jetty-io-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) ~[jetty-io-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117) ~[jetty-io-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806) ~[jetty-util-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938) ~[jetty-util-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: s=OPEN,api=BLOCKED,sc=false,e=null
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:767) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar!/:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:645) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:645) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:143) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeContent(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:137) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:129) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:45) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:227) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:489) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:53) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 73 common frames omitted
```

Can the problem be really related to the size of the HTML ? Because whenever I reduce the content of `api-docs.adoc` (which will later be transformed into a HTML), everything works.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Jetty: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/4461 We have setups with rather big HTMLs and no issues. However, we are using Tomcat and not Jetty. I suggest to try out Jetty 9.4.26 or later and see whether the issue still exists.

Comment: Exactly. There's a problem with that particular version of Jetty. Upgrading or downgrading to another version solved the problem. Thanks for the help !

Comment: Perfect. I have added the result as an answer so that others see it directly. Please accept the answer if you do not have any further feedback or comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Jetty: github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/4461 We have setups with rather big HTMLs and no issues. Jetty 9.4.26 or later should not have this bug anymore. Earlier versions of Jetty are also not affected.